# get name from a button click React

Tags: reactjs

Just some context with respect to the code. I currently have an array of objects which populates the label,icon, and id of a button accordingly in a loop. The trouble I am having is targeting the selected button upon click. Everytime I do click a button, i get the following the error:

> TypeError: _this2.props.bind is not a function

My code is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'
import Button from 'components/button'
import './segmentedButtons.scss'

class segmentedButtons extends Component {
  onChange = (displayLabels) => {
    console.log(displayLabels)
    //this.props.onChange({ label: displayLabels.label, icon: displayLabels.icon, id: displayLabels.id })
  }

  render() {
    const {displayLabels} = this.props.labels
    const classPrefix = this.props.view
    var renderLabels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< this.props.labels.length; i++){
        renderLabels.push(<Button
        label={this.props.labels[i].title}
        icon={this.props.labels[i].icon}
        id={this.props.labels[i].id}
        onClick={() => this.onChange(this.props.bind(this,i))}
      />)
    }

    return (
      <div className={classPrefix+"-buttons "+ "segmentedButtons-buttons"}>
          {renderLabels}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

segmentedButtons.propTypes = {
  displayLabels: propTypes.arrayOf(propTypes.shape({
    label: propTypes.string,
    icon: propTypes.string,
    id: propTypes.number,
    onClick: propTypes.func
  })),
}

export default segmentedButtons
```

Comment: What do you try to send with onchange parameter?

Comment: At the moment all i am trying to do is get what I have clicked to show up on the console.log(displayLabels)  in the onchange param.

Comment: try it `onClick={() => this.onChange(i)}` and `console.log(displayLabels)`

Comment: passing in (i) only returns back the final number of the loop. So if I have 5 objects looping through, itll return back 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Andrew mentioned, the best way is probably us use an arrow function: 
`onClick={() => this.onChange(i)}`.

If you want to use bind, this is the way to do it: `onClick={this.onChange.bind(this, i)}`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const onChangeGen = (i) => () => this.onChange(i)
```

and then

```
onClick={onChangeGen(i)}
```